# Permission denied when sudo npm install

Tags: react-native

i am getting this when trying to sudo npm install in my react-native template

[image]

I already tried to

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.npm 
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.config
```

Also I tried to manually create that folder, any idea?

Comment: Don't run `npm i` as root. Run normally.

Comment: https://medium.com/@ExplosionPills/dont-use-sudo-with-npm-still-66e609f5f92 discusses why `sudo` should never be used with `npm`. It addresses the security risk, and the problem of the forced install not belonging to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `sudo` command and then `npm install` in the other line